# Using HTML5 how can i send a simple string so I can see it?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a game written in HTML5 which is all fine and dandy. At the end of the game there is a score the player recieves. I want my game to send me how many people have a score of atleast 100 or above. I need this statistic to balance out the game accordingly.

I was thinking I could make a txt file in a dropbox account and make the game edit the file.

Now pls dont tell me about security issues I am aware that they can change their score in the javascript console which sends false data.

How do I go about solving this simple task? I just need a way to tell how many people are getting a score of 100 or above from my game.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Statistics, you say? Well you will need to save all that data somewehere. I recommend using PHP or similar for this task.

Comment: You will need server-side validation and maybe a cookie on the client for cross-checking.

Comment: Ok so PHP is my best bet? Thank you very much guys I will look into it :)

Comment: @user3288784 you do not "need php" you need a serverside language but node or ruby or c# or java or Erlang will do just as well. You'll also want a database and a server that is open to the internet. If they're not on the same domain you'll need CORS set up. If you do not have this stuff already it's not trivial. But I don't think that in YOUR situation you need any of this, see my reply.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use a server-side language such as PHP to write to a remote file.

Comment: Why specifically do you recommend php over any other web language and framework? please support your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

You will want to javascript something simple that when the the score is >100 (or whatever your threshold is) you would do a simple (probably ajax) query to a server.

While plenty of people are telling you to create a server-side app, if you do not already have a server, there are simpler ways to go. For example [I believe google spreadsheets has an api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) or even better you could use something like [Parse Data](https://www.parse.com/products/core#pricing) which is a free database-as-a-service with a simple javascript API and intended just for that purpose.

On the other hand, if you DO have a server but don't feel like setting up a full programming language to respond to API calls (which is NOT terribly hard by the way), you could use the server log. Whenever the user hits 100 points for example create a little invisible `<img src="http://yoursite.com/i-got-over-100" height=1 width=1 style="position: absolute, left: -10000" />` then just check your server logs for how much `i-got-over-100` was hit.